# Would this method of error checking be too costly in performance?

Tags: c++, optimization, error-handling

In my project, error handling and logging is performed through a class called `Error`.  Any function or object method which might need to log an error or warning, will have an `Error & error` as it's last function argument, and would call `Error::report(...)` if it encountered a problem.

An example of which would be:

```
float ratioBetweenBounds(  float between, 
                           float lowerBound, 
                           float upperBound, 
                           Error & error)    // <-- 
{
    if(upperBound != lowerBound){
        return (between - lowerBound) / (upperBound - lowerBound);
    }else{
        error.report(Error::DivideByZero, __LINE__, __FILE__, lowerBound); // <--
        return NAN;
    }
}
```

**My question is**, will passing a bulky reference like this cause performance problems to small functions that get called roughly 5,000 times per frame?  I would (and will!) profile it myself, but it'll be a few days until I can compile anything (on the road).  Maybe it's very obvious that it will or won't impact performance to SO though, and profiling won't be too necessary.

This has worked very well for me so far in terms of readability and debugging, so if the performance penalty is trivial, then I'd be happy with that.

(The only overhead I could see would be the added branch, but the branch predictor should take care of that.  It might also tip an already large function over so that it won't be inlined.  Outside of those things though, I have no clue really.  At the very least, it appears comparable and equal to any small performance hit a `try`/`catch` block would create, save that the branch for throwing would be statically biased against, I assume)

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as a "bulky reference".  Profiling can tell you the cost of doing it this way versus another way, but in the end you'll have to decide if the benefit outweighs the cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference is typically implemented by the compiler as a hidden pointer, so you're effectively adding a single pointer parameter to the function call. 5000 calls per frame is really not that much for a modern processor. Go ahead and profile, but I wouldn't worry about it unless it proves to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

*An optimisation trick that may be relevant:*

You can make the branch low-cost/free by making `error.report` a cold function. This way the compiler will generate code which tells the CPU that it's very unlikely it will be executed. It's more expensive, however, if it ever does.

```
// protect it with a macro for other platforms if necessary
#define COLD __attribute__((cold))

static void COLD error() {
  // unlikely error code
}
```

Documentation below (for GCC):

> **cold**
>   The cold attribute on functions is used to inform the compiler that the function is unlikely to be executed. The function is
>   optimized for size rather than speed and on many targets it is placed
>   into special subsection of the text section so all cold functions
>   appears close together improving code locality of non-cold parts of
>   program. The paths leading to call of cold functions within code are
>   marked as unlikely by the branch prediction mechanism. It is thus
>   useful to mark functions used to handle unlikely conditions, such as
>   perror, as cold to improve optimization of hot functions that do call
>   marked functions in rare occasions.

Then, if you can use "free" exceptions, or otherwise, the rest of your code under normal circumstances need not take any performance impact at all from the existence of your error checking/reporting.

Comment: I would use these if Visual Studio supported them, but they have nothing comparable to an `unlikely` hint unfortunately; I suppose PGO would know to do something comparable though. (as would GCC with the -fprofile-use switch on)